# transform a character string to a tidy tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
> dd <- tibble("Temper: 36.6℃  Pulse:76 bpm RR: 16bpm BP：148/58 mmHg")
> dd
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  `"Temper: 36.6℃  Pulse:76 bpm RR: 16bpm BP：148/58 mmHg"`
  <chr>                                                    
1 Temper: 36.6℃  Pulse:76 bpm RR: 16bpm BP：148/58 mmHg    
> ddtarget <- tibble(Temper=36.6,Pulse=76,RR=16,SBP=148,DBP=58)
> ddtarget
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  Temper Pulse    RR   SBP   DBP
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   36.6    76    16   148    58
```

I have a *dd* and want to get a *ddtarget*; How can I make it by using map or other tidyverse funnctions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can `rename` the column first (since it's weirdly named), get data in separate rows splitting on white-space followed by a capital letter, get data in different columns splitting on colon and finally get data in wide format using `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dd %>%
  rename(col = `"Temper: 36.6℃  Pulse:76 bpm RR: 16bpm BP：148/58 mmHg"`) %>%
  separate_rows(col, sep = "\\s+(?=[A-Z])") %>%
  separate(col, into = c('name', 'value'), sep = ':|：') %>%
  pivot_wider()

# A tibble: 1 x 4
#  Temper   Pulse  RR       BP         
#  <chr>    <chr>  <chr>    <chr>      
#1 " 36.6℃" 76 bpm " 16bpm" 148/58 mmHg
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a messy solution:

```
# String to convert to tibble: 

library(tidyverse)

dd <- tibble("Temper: 36.6℃  Pulse:76 bpm RR: 16bpm BP：148/58 mmHg")

# Store a vector of strings to become variables: 

dd_vars <-
  grep(":", unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(dd), "\\d+"),
                          function(w) {
                            x <- gsub(".* ", "", trimws(w, "both"))
                            y <- as.character(na.omit(ifelse(nchar(x) == 1, NA, x)))
                          })),
       value = TRUE)

# Store a vector of the strings to become values: 

dd_values <- iconv(gsub("[A-Za-z]", "", grep("\\d+", unlist(
  lapply(strsplit(as.character(dd), ":"),
         function(x) {
           gsub(" .*", "", trimws(x, "both"))
         })
),
value = TRUE)), 'utf-8', 'ascii', sub = '')

# Convert to a tibble with appropriate vectors: 

tib <-
  as_tibble(data.frame(lapply(within(setNames(
    data.frame(t(
      data.frame(vars = dd_vars,
                 values = as.character(dd_values))
    ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    gsub(":", "", dd_vars)
  )[-1, ],
  {
    SBP <- unlist(strsplit(BP, "/"))[1]
    DBP <- unlist(strsplit(BP, "/"))[2]
    rm(BP)
  }), as.numeric)))
```